# NVIDIA no additional drivers

Tags: boot, nvidia, 20.04, graphics, reboot

I have been having quite a few problems with NVIDIA drivers lately, It seems like my network drivers are also not working or simply deleted.

I have described the complete problem below

1. I had tones of mat files which occupied a lot of my disk space. My system stopped booting and so I had to remove them via recovery mode.
2. The system booted fine, however I wanted to selected a different NVIDIA driver and not the x.org nouveau nvidia driver. I selected NVIDIA 440 PPA driver (this was already an option in the additonal dirvers section) and I am sure I selected the one compatible with my graphics card.
3. However after selecting this when I tried to boot my system it got stuck, so I followed the following commands: I entered the recovery mode and went to root shell prompt.

   ```
   mount -o rw,remount /
   sudo apt purge nvidia-
   ```

   and rebooted my system, obviously after this I had no drivers in software and updates. My additional drivers was empty.
4. Therefore in order to add them I followed these steps.

   ```
   dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
   sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
   sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
   echo 'nouveau' | sudo tee -a
   sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
   ```

And then I had something like the image below.

[image]

This image is for reference only.

Unfortunately I had no internet or wifi connection and I thought that the manual divers were causing this issue so I deleted this driver and the system switched back to nouveau driver.

The issue is that it seems my network drivers are deleted, is there a way to restore them back? I would like to perform a complete OS reinstall.

I do not think the NVIDIA drivers issue and the networks drivers issue are related.

Also, if I switched to a 440 PPA driver which was compatible with my graphics card why did it cause any issues in the first place?

My network output:

[Network output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvJLI.jpg)

[Additional drivers, which was empty before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSzdb.png)

Note: I did not try to get the drivers from elsewhere,  I followed the commands in the question to restore them back as they were purged. I did not explicitly download and install them.

Comment: @weronika I have seen you give a similar answer to the networking issue. Do you think you could help me? Thanks.